# Find ideal defining $Gr_2(\mathbb{C}^5)$ in Pluker embedding

Tags: examples-counterexamples, grassmannian

Let $Gr_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$ the Grassmannian variety of $k$-planes in the complex space $\mathbb{C}^n$. We can consider the Pluker embedding
$$ \mathcal{P}: Gr_k(\mathbb{C}^n) \to \mathbb{P}(\Lambda^k \mathbb{C}^n) .$$
It is well known that Pluker coordinates satisfy the following relations:

$$\sum_{t=1}^{k+1}(-1)^tp(j_1, \cdots, j_{k-1},j_t^{'})p(j_1^{'}, \cdots,\hat{j}_t^{'}, \cdots, j_{k+1}^{'})=0.$$
Where $\{j_t\}_{t=1}^{t=k}$ and $\{j_t^{'}\}_{t=1}^{t=k+1}$ is any sequence in $[n]:=\{1,2, \cdots, n \}$.
How can I find explicitly the Pluker ideal $I_{2,5}$ generated by Pluker relations (about the Grassmannian $Gr_2(\mathbb{C}^5)$)?